Balls are different or same?

A bag contains $6$ red and $3$ white balls. Four balls are drawn one by one and not replaced. Find the probability that they are alternatively of different colours.

My Attempt:
RWRW or WRWR
$2\frac69\frac38\frac57\frac26=\frac5{42}$
It matches with the answer.
When I write $\frac69$, looks like I am writing $\frac{^6C_1}{^9C_1}$, does that mean the given balls are different?
What if the balls are same?
Edit:
My doubt is what if the balls of same colour are identical. i.e. 6 identical red balls. 3 identical white balls. How would we approach the question?
Also, just to confirm, in the given question, the balls of same colour are different, right?
Edit$2$:
Some thought process:
4 balls (4R, 0W),(3R,1W), (2R, 2W), (1R, 3W).
Since we want 2R,2W, so prob$=\frac14$
Also, for 2R,2W, we could have:
RRWW
RWRW
RWWR
WWRR
WRWR
WRRW
So, prob =2/6
So, final prob= 1/4*1/3=1/12.
Is that right?

Your two questions in the last two lines are not clear. Try to rephrase them.

@MOMO edited. Please check.

What matters here is how many balls of each colour remain when a selection is made.

@N.F.Taussig does that mean it won't matter if the balls of same colour are identical or not?

Yes, it does not matter whether or not the balls are distinguishable.

@N.F.Taussig I have made another edit. Please check.

In your second method, you have not taken into account the fact that a red ball is more likely to be drawn than a white ball.  Also, it is not possible to draw four of the three white balls.

@N.F.Taussig oh yes, big mistake, thanks, I'll edit

@N.F.Taussig I agree second method is incorrect as I haven't considered that the red ball is more likely to be drawn.

"just to confirm, in the given question, the balls of same colour are different, right?", Yes in this case, constraint is two colors but drawn in alternate manner

Whether the red and white balls are distinguishable (e.g., numbered
$R_1, R_2, \ldots, R_6$ and $W_1, W_2, W_3$) or identical, does not change the order of colors in the sequences required.

Your answer to the original question is correct, though it might be clearer if written as $\frac69\frac38\frac57\frac26+\frac39\frac68\frac27\frac56=\frac5{42}$ to match your "RWRW or WRWR". Here it is reasonable to say the two patterns $RWRW$ and $WRWR$ are equally likely, as you did implicitly, but it would better to do so explicitly and be prepared to prove it if necessary.
Your Edit 1 question, to the extent it is meaningful to say "balls of same colour are identical", would have the same answer, since you care about the order of the draw.  In reality all the balls are distinct even if you cannot identify the difference (for example they occupy different locations inside the bag) and if you get a different answer to an "identical balls" question then you should check you are not making the error of using a counting argument for events of different probability.
Your Edit 2 answer has a counting argument error.  The events of $(4R, 0W),(3R,1W), (2R, 2W), (1R, 3W)$ are of different probabilities, taken from a hypergeometric distribution, and you are wrong to say the probability of $(2R, 2W)$ is $\frac14$.  It is in fact $\frac{{6 \choose 2}{3 \choose 2}}{9 \choose 4}=\frac{5}{14}$, and when you multiply this by $\frac{2}{6}=\frac13$ (a correct application of a counting argument to the equally likely events $RRWW$, $\bf{RWRW}$, $RWWR$, $WRRW$, $\bf{WRWR}$, $WWRR$), you get the correct $\frac{5}{42}$ again.

It's a beautiful answer, thanks. But can we use $^6C_2$ on identical balls, the way you used in last para? Don't we use that for different objects?

@aarbee: Suppose you are choosing just $1$ ball from $6$ red and $3$ white.  The probability of getting $1$ red and $0$ white is $\frac{{6 \choose 1}{3 \choose 0}}{9 \choose1} =\frac69=\frac23$, and of getting $0$ red and $1$ white is $\frac{{6 \choose 0}{3 \choose 1}}{9 \choose1} =\frac39=\frac13$, whether or not the red balls are distinguishable and whether or not  the white balls are distinguishable.  The counting argument, of saying that there are two possibilities $R$ or $W$ and so the probability is $\frac12$ for red and $\frac12$ for white, is obviously wrong.

Maybe I am getting brainfog because I am not able to grasp the concept. If we have 6 identical balls. To choose two, can we write 6C2?

@aarbee That would be a number, but you are interested in probabilities.  If you wanted the probability all four balls drawn without replacement were red, $\frac{6 \choose 4}{9\choose 4} = \frac5{42}$ would be correct even if the red balls were identical.  Similarly $\frac{3 \choose 4}{9\choose 4} = 0$ would give you the correct probability all four balls were white.

Thanks, that's new info for me. For further doubts, I'll open a new thread and post the link here.
